# Extract JSON from HTML Script tag with BeautifulSoup in Python

Tags: python, html, json, beautifulsoup

I have the following HTML, and what should I do to extract the JSON from the variable: `window.__INITIAL_STATE__`

```
<!DOCTYPE doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<script>
                  window.sessConf = "-2912474957111138742";
                  /* <sl:translate_json> */
                  window.__INITIAL_STATE__ = { /* Target JSON here with 12 million characters */};
                  /* </sl:translate_json> */
                </script>
</html>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Is the 12 million character json all in a single line? That would simplify the answer a lot.

Comment: @JeffUK I've tried get all text from the script tag, then split('\n'), but it somehow break the JSON into couple substrings.

Comment: @solarc yes, it is a single line JSON.

Comment: Do you have `nodejs` in your system?

Comment: @gdlmx No, do I have to get it in the system?

Comment: It will be easier and more robust to run JS code in Node. I am writing an answer...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following Python code to extract the JavaScript code.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
s=soup.find('script')
js = 'window = {};\n'+s.text.strip()+';\nprocess.stdout.write(JSON.stringify(window.__INITIAL_STATE__));'
with open('temp.js','w') as f:
    f.write(js)
```

The JS code will be written to a file "temp.js". Then you can call `node` to execute the JS file.

```
from subprocess import check_output
window_init_state = check_output(['node','temp.js'])
```

The python variable `window_init_state` contains the JSON string of the JS object `window.__INITIAL_STATE__`, which you can parse in python with `JSONDecoder`.

#### Example

```py
from subprocess import check_output
import json, bs4
html='''<!DOCTYPE doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<script> window.sessConf = "-2912474957111138742";
                  /* <sl:translate_json> */
                  window.__INITIAL_STATE__ = { 'Hello':'World'};
                  /* </sl:translate_json> */
                </script>
</html>'''
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html)
with open('temp.js','w') as f:
    f.write('window = {};\n'+
            soup.find('script').text.strip()+
            ';\nprocess.stdout.write(JSON.stringify(window.__INITIAL_STATE__));')
window_init_state = check_output(['node','temp.js'])
print(json.loads(window_init_state))
```

Output:

```
{'Hello': 'World'}
```

Comment: I got: FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified      from the check_output. Would it potentially caused by     with open('temp.js','w') as f     ?

Comment: That's probably because the program `node` is not included in your `PATH` environmental variable. Have you successfully installed it?

Comment: If you are not sure where the `nodejs` has been installed. You can it lookup at the locations listed [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/nodejs_environment_setup.htm).

Comment: I have a further question, is there a way to avoid writing the js file into hard drive, but achieve the same goal?

Comment: Yes. Try using `check_output(['node','-e', your_js_script])` where `your_js_script` is a python string variable that contains the JS script.

Comment: I tried, but got: FileNotFoundError: [WinError 206] The filename or extension is too long ..... Would it because of the length of the python string, which has 12 million length?

Comment: Yes. There's limitation to the length of command line argument.

Answer (score 0):

gdlmx's code is correct and very helpfull.

```
from subprocess import check_output
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
s=soup.find('script')
js = 'window = {};\n'+s.text.strip()+';\nprocess.stdout.write(JSON.stringify(window.__INITIAL_STATE__));'
window_init_state = check_output(['node','temp.js'])
```

type(window_init_state) will be . So then you shuld use following code.

```
jsonData= window_init_state.decode("utf-8")
```

Comment: What are you trying to tell us? :)
In your check_output line a "temp.js" is mentioned which isn't part of your answer