# beautiful soup find_all() not returning all elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape [this](https://www.cardekho.com/used-cars+in+bangalore) website using bs4. Using inspect on particular car ad tile, I figured what I need to scrape in order to get the title & the link to the car's page.

I am making use of the find_all() function of the bs4 library but the issue is that it's not scraping the required info of all the cars. It returns only info of about 21, whereas it's clearly visible on the website that there are about 2410 cars.

The relevant code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen 
import re
import requests

url = 'https://www.cardekho.com/used-cars+in+bangalore'
req = Request(url , headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
webpage = urlopen(req).read()

page_soup = bs(webpage,"html.parser")

tags = page_soup.find_all("div","title")

print(len(tags))
```

How to get info on all of the cars present on the page.

P.S - Want to point out just one thing, all the cars aren't displayed at once. More car info gets loaded as you scroll down. Could it because of that? Not sure.

Comment: "More car info gets loaded as you scroll down." -- looks like javascript is used to load additional content. You'll need something like Selenium to execute javascript.

Comment: When you inspect the site you'll see that, when scrolling, it loads new cars from an api endpoint in json format. You can loop over the pages in the api url to get the additional cars.

Comment: Hi!  @RJAdriaansen . Thanks for commenting on this post. I'm a beginner when it comes to scrapping so I'm not fully sure if I've understood what you are pointing at. Could please provide me with an eg? I'd be really glad.

Comment: @JustinEzequiel

Comment: @vishalsingh I've posted an answer to help you get started

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've written up a sample code to show you how it can be done. Although the site has a convenient api that we can leverage, the first page is not available through the api, but is embedded in a `script` tag in the `html` code. This requires additional processing to extract. After that it is simply a matte of getting the json data from the api, parsing it to python dictionaries and appending the car entries to a list. The link to the api can be found when inspecting [network activity](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network) in Chrome or Firefox while scrolling the site.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import json
from subprocess import check_output
import requests
import time
from tqdm import tqdm #tqdm is just to implement a progress bar, https://pypi.org/project/tqdm/

cars = [] #create empty list to which we will append the car dicts from the json data

url = 'https://www.cardekho.com/used-cars+in+bangalore'
r = requests.get(url , headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content.decode('utf-8'),"html.parser")
s = soup.find('script', {"type":"application/ld+json"}).next_sibling #find the section with the json data. It looks for a script tage with application/ld+json type, and takes the next tag, which is the one with the data we need, see page source code

js = 'window = {};\n'+s.text.strip()+';\nprocess.stdout.write(JSON.stringify(window.__INITIAL_STATE__));' #strip the text from unnecessary strings and load the json as python dict, taken from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54991571/extract-json-from-html-script-tag-with-beautifulsoup-in-python/54992015#54992015
with open('temp.js','w') as f: # save the sting to a javascript file
    f.write(js)

data_site = json.loads(check_output(['node','temp.js'])) #execute the file with node, which will return the json data that will be loaded with json.loads.
for i in data_site['items']: #iterate over the dict and append all cars to the empty list 'cars'
  cars.append(i)

for page in tqdm(range(20, data_site['total_count'], 20)): #'pagefrom' in the api call is 20, 40, 60, etc. so create a range and loop it
  r = requests.get(f"https://www.cardekho.com/api/v1/usedcar/search?&cityId=105&connectoid=&lang_code=en&regionId=0&searchstring=used-cars%2Bin%2Bbangalore&pagefrom={page}&sortby=updated_date&sortorder=asc&mink=0&maxk=200000&dealer_id=&regCityNames=&regStateNames=", headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
  data = r.json()

  for i in data['data']['cars']: #iterate over the dict and append all cars to the empty list 'cars'
    cars.append(i)

  time.sleep(5) #wait a few seconds to avoid overloading the site
```

This will result in `cars` being a list of dictionaries. The car names can be found in the `vid` key, and the urls are present in the `vlink` key.
You can load it into a pandas dataframe to explore the data:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(cars)
```

`df.head()` will output (I omitted the images column for readability):

|  | loc | myear | bt | ft | km | it | pi | pn | pu | dvn | ic | ucid | sid | ip | oem | model | vid | city | vlink | p_numeric | webp_image | position | pageNo | centralVariantId | isExpiredModel | modelId | isGenuine | is_ftc | seller_location | utype | views | tmGaadiStore | cls |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Koramangala | 2014 | SUV | Diesel | 30,000 | 0 | https://images10.gaadicdn.com/usedcar_image/320x240/used_car_2206305_1614944913.jpg |  | 9.9 Lakh | Mahindra XUV500 W6 2WD | 13 | 3019084 | 9509A09F1673FE2566DF59EC54AAC05B | 1 | Mahindra | Mahindra XUV500 | Mahindra XUV500 2011-2015 W6 2WD | Bangalore | /used-car-details/used-Mahindra-XUV500-2011-2015-W6-2WD-cars-Bangalore_9509A09F1673FE2566DF59EC54AAC05B.htm | 990000 | https://images10.gaadicdn.com/usedcar_image/320x240webp/2021/used_car_2206305_1614944913.webp | 1 | 1 | 3822 | True | 570 | 0 | 0 | {'address': 'BDA Complex, 100 Feet Rd, 3rd Block, Koramangala 3 Block, Koramangala, Bengaluru, Karnataka 560034, Bangalore', 'lat': 12.931, 'lng': 77.6228} | Dealer | 235 | False |  |
| 1 | Marathahalli Colony | 2017 | SUV | Petrol | 30,000 | 0 | https://images10.gaadicdn.com/usedcar_image/320x240/used_car_2203506_1614754307.jpeg |  | 7.85 Lakh | Ford Ecosport 1.5 Petrol Trend BSIV | 14 | 3015331 | 2C0E4C4E543D4792C1C3186B361F718B | 1 | Ford | Ford Ecosport | Ford Ecosport 2015-2021 1.5 Petrol Trend BSIV | Bangalore | /used-car-details/used-Ford-Ecosport-2015-2021-1.5-Petrol-Trend-BSIV-cars-Bangalore_2C0E4C4E543D4792C1C3186B361F718B.htm | 785000 | https://images10.gaadicdn.com/usedcar_image/320x240webp/2021/used_car_2203506_1614754307.webp | 2 | 1 | 6086 | True | 175 | 0 | 0 | {'address': '2, Varthur Rd, Ayyappa Layout, Chandra Layout, Marathahalli, Bengaluru, Karnataka 560037, Marathahalli Colony, Bangalore', 'lat': 12.956727624875453, 'lng': 77.70174980163576} | Dealer | 495 | False |  |
| 2 | Yelahanka | 2020 | SUV | Diesel | 13,969 | 0 | https://images10.gaadicdn.com/usedcar_image/320x240/usedcar_11_276591614316705_1614316747.jpg |  | 41 Lakh | Toyota Fortuner 2.8 4WD AT | 12 | 3007934 | BBC13FB62DF6840097AA62DDEA05BB04 | 1 | Toyota | Toyota Fortuner | Toyota Fortuner 2016-2021 2.8 4WD AT | Bangalore | /used-car-details/used-Toyota-Fortuner-2016-2021-2.8-4WD-AT-cars-Bangalore_BBC13FB62DF6840097AA62DDEA05BB04.htm | 4100000 | https://images10.gaadicdn.com/usedcar_image/320x240webp/2021/usedcar_11_276591614316705_1614316747.webp | 3 | 1 | 7618 | True | 364 | 0 | 0 | {'address': 'Sonnappanahalli Kempegowda Intl Airport Road Jala Uttarahalli Hobli, Yelahanka, Bangalore, Karnataka 560064', 'lat': 13.1518821, 'lng': 77.6220694} | Dealer | 516 | False |  |
| 3 | Byatarayanapura | 2017 | Sedans | Diesel | 18,000 | 0 | https://images10.gaadicdn.com/usedcar_image/320x240/used_car_2202297_1615013237.jpg |  | 35 Lakh | Mercedes-Benz E-Class E250 CDI Avantgarde | 15 | 3013606 | 4553943A967049D873712AFFA5F65A56 | 1 | Mercedes-Benz | Mercedes-Benz E-Class | Mercedes-Benz E-Class 2009-2012 E250 CDI Avantgarde | Bangalore | /used-car-details/used-Mercedes-Benz-E-Class-2009-2012-E250-CDI-Avantgarde-cars-Bangalore_4553943A967049D873712AFFA5F65A56.htm | 3500000 | https://images10.gaadicdn.com/usedcar_image/320x240webp/2021/used_car_2202297_1615013237.webp | 4 | 1 | 4611 | True | 674 | 0 | 0 | {'address': 'NO 19, Near Traffic Signal, Byatanarayanapura, International Airport Road, Byatarayanapura, Bangalore, Karnataka 560085', 'lat': 13.0669588, 'lng': 77.5928756} | Dealer | 414 | False |  |
| 4 | nan | 2015 | Sedans | Diesel | 80,000 | 0 | https://stimg.cardekho.com/pwa/img/noimage.svg |  | 12.5 Lakh | Skoda Octavia Elegance 2.0 TDI AT | 1 | 3002709 | 156E5F2317C0A3A3BF8C03FFC35D404C | 1 | Skoda | Skoda Octavia | Skoda Octavia 2013-2017 Elegance 2.0 TDI AT | Bangalore | /used-car-details/used-Skoda-Octavia-2013-2017-Elegance-2.0-TDI-AT-cars-Bangalore_156E5F2317C0A3A3BF8C03FFC35D404C.htm | 1250000 |  | 5 | 1 | 3092 | True | 947 | 0 | 0 | {'lat': 0, 'lng': 0} | Individual | 332 | False |  |

Or if you wish to explode the dict in `seller_location` to columns, you can load it with `df = pd.json_normalize(cars)`.

You can save all data to a `csv` file: `df.to_csv('output.csv')`

Comment: What a massive effort sir!. Thanks so much for your help. I just had doubt with some of the code. I don't think I've understood the following code.

Comment: s = soup.find('script', {"type":"application/ld+json"}).next_sibling |

data_site = json.loads(check_output(['node','temp.js']))

Comment: r = requests.get(f"https://www.cardekho.com/api/v1/usedcar/search? ....... , headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}) .

Comment: I have added some additional explanation . The `check_output` is a hack to extract the json embedded in the page [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54991571/extract-json-from-html-script-tag-with-beautifulsoup-in-python/54992015#54992015). From then onwards, when scrolling the site loads data from the [api url](https://www.cardekho.com/api/v1/usedcar/search?&cityId=105&connectoid=&lang_code=en&regionId=0&searchstring=used-cars%2Bin%2Bbangalore&pagefrom=20&sortby=updated_date&sortorder=asc&mink=0&maxk=200000&dealer_id=&regCityNames=&regStateNames=).