# How can I select the variable of inside of script tag as JSON value?

Tags: javascript, python, json, beautifulsoup, python-requests

https://www.canparkavm.com.tr/tr/markalar

As i said at title, how can i access/convert JavaScript variable as JSON value on Python using the  `BeautifulSoup` and `requests` libraries?

I tried this topic for solve my problem but did not worked actually: [Extract JSON from HTML Script tag with BeautifulSoup in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54991571/extract-json-from-html-script-tag-with-beautifulsoup-in-python)

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, json
from subprocess import check_output


def main():
    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36'
    }
    url = "https://www.canparkavm.com.tr/tr/markalar"
    req = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    bs4 = BeautifulSoup(req.content, "lxml")
    data = bs4.find("body").find("script").find_next("script")
    with open('temp.js', 'w') as f:
        f.write('stores = {};\n' + data.text.strip() + '\nprocess.stdout.write(JSON.stringify(stores));')
    window_init_state = check_output(['node', 'temp.js'])
    print(json.loads(window_init_state))
    
main()
```

Script tag is inside of HTML.
This is script tag which i tried to scrap JSON value from `stores` variable:

```
<script>

    var language = "tr";
    var stores = [
  {
    "store_categories": [
      {
        "store_category_tr_tags": [],
        "store_category_en_tags": [],
        "_id": "4yc8Q95d-",
        "store_category_name_tr": "Yeme & İçme",
        "store_category_name_en": "Food & Beverage",
        "store_category_mallid": "NkYFwYyO-"
      }
    ],
    "store_tags": [],
    "store_locations": [
      {
        "location_pin": {
          "z": 0,
          "x": 7475,
          "y": 4043
        },
        "location_serviceids": [],
        "location_belongs_to_nodes": [
          "B1ZlzrSdA0F"
        ],
        "_id": "EJ1xCinc-OZ",
        "location_id": "K0_store_43",
        "location_mallid": "NkYFwYyO-",
        "location_floorid": {
          "floor_number": 0,
          "_id": "4Jk1uMxdW",
          "floor_name_tr": "Zemin Kat",
          "floor_name_en": "Ground Floor"
        },
        "location_storeid": "NJgYCfWg_-"
      }
    ],
    "store_promotions": [
      "41yxPW1hB"
    ],
    "store_will_use_big_logo": false,
    "_id": "NJgYCfWg_-",
    "store_slug": "alacati-muhallebicisi",
    "store_mallid": "NkYFwYyO-",
    "store_brandid": {
      "_id": "4ym42U_JOb",
      "brand_id": 2271,
      "brand_name": "Alaçatı Muhallebici",
      "brand_logo": "https://d3heiv85u05n2u.cloudfront.net/images/brands/2271_low.jpg?1429088370",
      "brand_web": "http://www.alacatimuhallebicisi.com",
      "brand_whitescale_logo": "https://d3heiv85u05n2u.cloudfront.net/images/brands/2271_whitescale_low.png?1482761569",
      "brand_logo_high": "https://d3heiv85u05n2u.cloudfront.net/images/brands/2271_original.jpg?1429088370",
      "brand_whitescale_logo_high": "https://d3heiv85u05n2u.cloudfront.net/images/brands/2271_whitescale_original.png?1482761569"
    },
    "store_name": "ALAÇATI MUHALLEBİCİSİ",
    "store_email": "",
    "store_web": "http://www.alacatimuhallebicisi.com",
    "store_phone": "0216 504 51 18",
    "store_description_tr": "",
    "store_description_en": "",
    "store_primary_image": {
      "main": "https://s3-eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/klepierre/images/store_primary_image/NJgYCfWg_--main.jpeg?1470234948279"
    }
  },
  {
    "store_categories": [
      {
        "store_category_tr_tags": [],
        "store_category_en_tags": [],
        "_id": "NkSYmq9db",
        "store_category_name_tr": "Sinema & Eğlence",
        "store_category_name_en": "Fun",
        "store_category_mallid": "NkYFwYyO-"
      }
    ],
    "store_tags": [],
    "store_locations": [
      {
        "location_pin": {
          "z": 3,
          "x": 1832,
          "y": 3989
        },
        "location_serviceids": [],
        "location_belongs_to_nodes": [
          "HkBHMHBORCY"
        ],
        "_id": "Vyy4Cj29Zdb",
        "location_id": "K3_store_123q124",
        "location_mallid": "NkYFwYyO-",
        "location_floorid": {
          "floor_number": 3,
          "_id": "V1bjvfxuZ",
          "floor_name_tr": "Kat 3",
          "floor_name_en": "Floor 3"
        },
        "location_storeid": "VJWEJQWxdZ"
      },
      {
        "location_pin": {
          "z": 3,
          "x": 9885,
          "y": 3872
        },
        "location_serviceids": [],
        "location_belongs_to_nodes": [
          "SkVIGSB_R0F"
        ],
        "_id": "NyJS0o25b_Z",
        "location_id": "K3_store_136q138",
        "location_mallid": "NkYFwYyO-",
        "location_floorid": {
          "floor_number": 3,
          "_id": "V1bjvfxuZ",
          "floor_name_tr": "Kat 3",
          "floor_name_en": "Floor 3"
        },
        "location_storeid": "VJWEJQWxdZ"
      }
    ],
    "store_promotions": [
      "EkC2w99hS",
      "r1X-WHouN"
    ],
    "store_will_use_big_logo": false,
    "_id": "VJWEJQWxdZ",
    "store_slug": "atlantis-fun-city",
    "store_mallid": "NkYFwYyO-",
    "store_brandid": {
      "_id": "ByPu9oyvB",
      "brand_id": 5431,
      "brand_name": "Atlantis Fun City",
      "brand_logo": "https://ams3.digitaloceanspaces.com/cinebrand/images/brand/brand_logo/6d1a86e9-3d27-4dfa-9318-dc8855dcf839.png?1568811042923",
      "brand_logo_high": "https://ams3.digitaloceanspaces.com/cinebrand/images/brand/brand_logo/0fb05193-2af0-4607-be17-a965d1b509c5.png?1568811042667"
    },
    "store_name": "ATLANTİS FUN CITY",
    "store_email": "cemil.coskun@atlantisbowling.com",
    "store_web": "",
    "store_phone": "0544 258 34 22 ",
    "store_description_tr": "",
    "store_description_en": "",
    "store_primary_image": {
      "main": "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/canpark/images/store_primary_image/VJWEJQWxdZ-main.jpeg?1560243207859"
    }
  },
  {
    "store_categories": [
      {
        "store_category_tr_tags": [],
        "store_category_en_tags": [],
        "_id": "Eyvibc5uZ",
        "store_category_name_tr": "Hazır Giyim",
        "store_category_name_en": "Clothing",
        "store_category_mallid": "NkYFwYyO-"
      }
    ],
    "store_tags": [],
    "store_locations": [
      {
        "location_pin": {
          "z": 1,
          "x": 8974,
          "y": 3054
        },
        "location_serviceids": [],
        "location_belongs_to_nodes": [
          "HJUfGrrOR0F"
        ],
        "_id": "EkhZAi3qZ_b",
        "location_id": "K1_store_79",
        "location_mallid": "NkYFwYyO-",
        "location_floorid": {
          "floor_number": 1,
          "_id": "VkeCvMxOZ",
          "floor_name_tr": "Kat 1",
          "floor_name_en": "Floor 1"
        },
        "location_storeid": "Vk7jAMZxOW"
      }
    ],
    "store_promotions": [
      "Sy8FFoc2B",
      "HywcrnjRH"
    ],
    "store_will_use_big_logo": false,
    "_id": "Vk7jAMZxOW",
    "store_slug": "aker",
    "store_mallid": "NkYFwYyO-",
    "store_brandid": {
      "_id": "4Jzz28OJub",
      "brand_id": 535,
      "brand_name": "Aker",
      "brand_logo": "https://d3heiv85u05n2u.cloudfront.net/images/brands/535_low.jpg?1376916442",
      "brand_web": "http://www.aker.com.tr",
      "brand_whitescale_logo": "https://d3heiv85u05n2u.cloudfront.net/images/brands/535_whitescale_low.png?1472804453",
      "brand_logo_high": "https://d3heiv85u05n2u.cloudfront.net/images/brands/535_original.jpg?1376916442",
      "brand_whitescale_logo_high": "https://d3heiv85u05n2u.cloudfront.net/images/brands/535_whitescale_original.png?1472804453"
    },
    "store_name": "Aker",
    "store_email": "gulnurkir@gmail.com.tr",
    "store_web": "http://www.aker.com.tr",
    "store_phone": "0216 999 37 83",
    "store_description_tr": "",
    "store_description_en": "",
    "store_primary_image": {
      "main": "https://s3-eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/klepierre/images/store_primary_image/Vk7jAMZxOW-main.jpeg?1470234918440"
    }
  },
  {
    "store_categories": [
      {
        "store_category_tr_tags": [],
        "store_category_en_tags": [],
        "_id": "Eyvibc5uZ",
        "store_category_name_tr": "Hazır Giyim",
        "store_category_name_en": "Clothing",
        "store_category_mallid": "NkYFwYyO-"
      }
    ],
    "store_tags": [],
    "store_locations": [
      {
        "location_pin": {
          "z": 1,
          "x": 4842,
          "y": 3029
        },
        "location_serviceids": [],
        "location_belongs_to_nodes": [
          "ByK-GHSdCCK"
        ],
        "_id": "4kz-Co2cWuZ",
        "location_id": "K1_store_86",
        "location_mallid": "NkYFwYyO-",
        "location_floorid": {
          "floor_number": 1,
          "_id": "VkeCvMxOZ",
          "floor_name_tr": "Kat 1",
          "floor_name_en": "Floor 1"
        },
        "location_storeid": "EkNoCfZlub"
      }
    ],
    "store_promotions": [
      "VyLvwZy2r"
    ],
    "store_will_use_big_logo": false,
    "_id": "EkNoCfZlub",
    "store_slug": "altinyildiz-classics",
    "store_mallid": "NkYFwYyO-",
    "store_brandid": {
      "_id": "V1nYjVTsN",
      "brand_id": 4363,
      "brand_name": "Altınyıldız Classics",
      "brand_logo": "https://d3heiv85u05n2u.cloudfront.net/images/brands/4363_low.jpg?1521447270",
      "brand_logo_high": "https://d3heiv85u05n2u.cloudfront.net/images/brands/4363_original.jpg?1521447270",
      "brand_whitescale_logo": "https://ams3.digitaloceanspaces.com/cinebrand/images/brand/brand_whitescale_logo/ae8e1fff-241b-4046-9943-be8ffa704cec.png?1559033647723",
      "brand_whitescale_logo_high": "https://ams3.digitaloceanspaces.com/cinebrand/images/brand/brand_whitescale_logo/8008a25a-95a3-4da8-8b56-90340ccadfd0.png?1559033633724",
      "brand_web": ""
    },
    "store_name": "Altınyıldız Classics",
    "store_email": "ercan_krmn@hotmail.com",
    "store_web": "",
    "store_phone": "0216 519 16 06",
    "store_description_tr": "",
    "store_description_en": "",
    "store_primary_image": {
      "main": "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/canpark/images/store_primary_image/EkNoCfZlub-main.jpeg?1559032279151"
    }
  },
  {
    "store_categories": [
      {
        "store_category_tr_tags": [],
        "store_category_en_tags": [],
        "_id": "4yc8Q95d-",
        "store_category_name_tr": "Yeme & İçme",
        "store_category_name_en": "Food & Beverage",
        "store_category_mallid": "NkYFwYyO-"
      }
    ],
    "store_tags": [],
    "store_locations": [
      {
        "location_pin": {
          "z": 3,
          "x": 2274,
          "y": 4510
        },
        "location_serviceids": [],
        "location_belongs_to_nodes": [
          "rkESfSBu0RY"
        ],
        "_id": "41R7Rs3cbOb",
        "location_id": "K3_store_125",
        "location_mallid": "NkYFwYyO-",
        "location_floorid": {
          "floor_number": 3,
          "_id": "V1bjvfxuZ",
          "floor_name_tr": "Kat 3",
          "floor_name_en": "Floor 3"
        },
        "location_storeid": "EkNq8ZwTZ"
      }
    ],
    "store_promotions": [],
    "store_will_use_big_logo": false,
    "_id": "EkNq8ZwTZ",
    "store_slug": "arden",
    "store_brandid": {
      "_id": "NJpvrWvpW",
      "brand_id": 3433,
      "brand_name": "Arden",
      "brand_logo": "http…</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find a suitable regex pattern to grab that content. One such is as follows:

```
import re, json, requests

r = requests.get('https://www.canparkavm.com.tr/tr/markalar')
data = json.loads(re.search(r'var stores = ([\s\S]+)?;\s+var floor', r.text).group(1))
data
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I must learn how to use "re" and you showed the reason.